# Matlab batch not passing arguments to function

Tags: matlab

Thank you in advance for any help you can give. I am relatively new to Matlab and am stuck with the use of the batch command for passing arguments to the function. I have tried to simplify the example as much as possible.

Following the documentation, I can get it to work with a built-in function:

```
>> 
>> j = batch(@zeros,1,{10,1});
>> a=fetchOutputs(j)

a =

  1×1 cell array

    {10×1 double}

>> a{1}

ans =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

I then created a simple stand-along function runTest.m:

```
function result = runTest(n1,n2) 
result = zeros(n1,n2);
end
```

It works with a direct call:

```
>> a=runTest(5,1)

a =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

But, it doesn't work using batch:

```
>> j = batch(runTest,1,{5,1});
Not enough input arguments.

Error in runTest (line 2)
result = zeros(n1,n2);
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```matlab
j = batch(runTest,1,{5,1});
```

then the part of that statement that reads `runTest` tries to call the function `runTest` with no input arguments. This is where the error happens. It never gets to call `batch`.

Like in just about every other programming language, the arguments to a function call are evaluated before the function is called, evaluating `runTest` is the same as evaluating `runTest()`, MATLAB makes no distinction between the two.

What you intended to write was

```matlab
j = batch(@runTest,1,{5,1});
```